# Multiple connected one line charts with angular-nvd3

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

Is there is a way to create multiple connected one line charts with `useInteractiveGuideline=true` options. Such need is become when you need to show 3 different types of data on one graph (E.g. Fuel status, Engine working hours and water tank status ). Attached example by `jquery-dygraph`.

[image]

I tried to do this using ng-repeat, but only firts chart appears:

`<div ng-repeat="data in widget.widgetData">
    <nvd3 options="widget.widgetOptions" data="data" api="widget.api" on-ready="widget.onReadyCallback"></nvd3>
</div>`

where widget.widgetData is:

`widget.widgetData = [[charts.fuelData],[charts.engineHoursData]];`

My inner widget data object is:

`fuelData: { values: [], key: 'Fuel', color: '#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16), strokeWidth: 1, classed: '' },
   engineHoursData: { values: [], key: 'Engine Hours', color: '#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16), strokeWidth: 1, classed: '' }`

If there is an option to do such behavior in this directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was posted [here](https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/606)
If anybody need more deatils, you are welcome to ask :):):):):)